# Logical operators confusion

Tags: javascript

```
var first = prompt("Enter the first number");
var second = prompt("Enter the second numbers");

var number1 = parseInt(first);
var number2 = parseInt(second);


if(isNaN(number1 || number2)){
    document.write("invalid, not a number");

};
```

Why doesn't the operator or (||) works in the above example? It works with and (&&) operator but i can't understand the logic behind. Am i not basically telling the computer that if number1 **or** number2 is not a number print this?

demo here

https://jsfiddle.net/tc3mhL1u/

Comment: Yup, you're telling the computer that if `number1` (or, if `number1` is falsy, `number2`) is not a number, then print something. Of course, that's not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isNaN()` separately for variables `first` and `second`:

```
var 
  first = +prompt("Enter the first number"),
  second = +prompt("Enter the second numbers");

if(isNaN(first) || isNaN(second)){

  alert("invalid, not a number");
}
else {

  alert('Yay!');
}
```

Read more about [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

In your example you use an expression `number1 || number2`. It looks like this sample:

```
var result = 1 || 0; // 1

var result = 0 || 44; // 44
```

As result your single isNaN will check only one of your input parameters:

```
isNaN(1 || 0) -> isNaN(1) -> false

isNaN(0 || 44) -> isNaN(44) -> false
```

> **Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition:** if JavaScript encounters a non-Boolean expression as an operand in a
>   logical operation, the non-Boolean is returned as a result. This
>   behavior is not something you should rely on because it makes the code
>   harder to understand.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is clear and simply thanks for the link also. I just can't understand why it works with && operator, shouldn't print true if both values were true? true && true -- true both values are not numbers so the if activates. But if you put a number  and a string as values false && true -- false, it shouldn't print, but the if still gets activated.

Comment: @DimitrisXydas, lets use an example: `isNaN(4 && 3)`, `4 && 3` -> `3`, so `isNaN(3)` -> `false`. As you see there is a problem with `&&` operator too. It doesn't work as expected. "But if you put a number and a string" -> your script will not catch this case, becase you are using `parseInt` function. It will return a primitive number data or a NaN (but never string)

Comment: @AliMamedov Thank you very much for the time you put on all of this, i now understand it and thanks for the book title will have to read on the future!

Answer (score 1):

You see, if you are using the || inside the isNaN() function, the or is being considered Differently. The function result is false as one of your two var IS a number :

> isNaN(true || false) = false

If you do this instead :

```
if(isNaN(number1) || isNaN(number2)){
    document.write("invalid, not a number");}
```

Then you are considering every var separately in isNaN, so if one of the results is true and the other is false, the if() consider :

> if(true || false) = true

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot.